# Is one permitted to change one of Hashem’s names to another in writing?

Tags: shemos-sacred-names, safrus, torah-writing

If someone had in mind to write  the name א-ל, would he be allowed to turn it afterwards into א-להים?

Comment: You can't write א-להים without writing א-ל first.

Comment: @shmose well, not in order anyway

Comment: @DoubleAA I was waiting for that comment :)

Comment: Nor can you write י-ה-ו-ה without י-ה first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don’t have an exact source for this question, I found the reverse case that is discussed and this case can be inferred from that.

If someone wrote Elokim and wants to erase part of it to say only Kel, the Pischai Teshuva [YD 276:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Pitchei_Teshuva_on_Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De%27ah?tab=contents) says that it’s permitted. If so, logic should say that this case is for sure permitted.

> במי שהיה צריך לכתוב שם קטן וכתב שם גדול כגון שהיה צריך לכתוב י"ה או אל וכ' יהו"ה או אלהים וכמו כן בהוסיף וכתב אותיות הנטפלים במקום שאינו צריך אי יכול למחוק ולעשות משם גדול שם קטן והאריך בזה והביא סמוכים להתיר דאף לדעת הפוסקים האוסרים מוחק ע"מ לתקן לא אסרו כ"א במוחק ואח"כ מתקן אבל היכא דבמחיקה גופא מתקן לא מקרי מחיקה כלל רק תיקון ואף דבנ"ד לא נפסל השם מתחלה רק נכתב שלא במקומו שרי למחוק

Answer (score 2):

The Minchas Chinuch (437) that erasing some letters of a Divine Name is forbidden even if the remainder constitutes a different Divine Name.

> ומבואר בר"מ דהמוחק אות אחת משמות אלו לוקין. ופשוט ל"מ אם מוחק אות מהשם
> דעי"ז אינו נקרא הו"ל בודאי מוחק כגון למחוק א' מאלקים ובלא א' אינו נקרא
> השם כלל **אלא אפילו מחק אותיות מהשם ונשאר שם אחר** כגון הי' מאלקים דנשאר
> אל וכדומה מכל מקום לוקין דעכ"פ מחק שם זה והוא עתה שם אחר וז"פ עיין
> בר"מ ובטור ובכ"מ ובב"י.

The Minchas Chinuch asserts that adding a letter which will invalidate the Name is considerd *mechikah* (although he assumes it isn't punishable).

> ונראה אם רצה לכתוב שם י' ה' לחוד אסור לכתוב וא"ו אח"כ לחוד דמקלקל השם
> דמעיקרא היה שם י' ה' ועתה יה"ו אינו שם כלל.

He discusses further why one is permitted to write אלקים or יקוק, since both of these contain shorter Divine Names, and by adding the third letter one is already *mochek*.

> ולכאורה קשה לי דבכותב שם
> הויה ב"ה דכותב י' ה' והוי שם ואח"כ כותב הו' ובאותו רגע הוי קלקול כי
> אין זה שם אלא אח"כ כשכותב ה' האחרונה נגמר השם

He explains that this isn't strictly forbidden, because it is מקלקל על מנת לתקן, but that shouldn't be allowed *lechatchila*. He proceeds in a lengthy discussion about why one isn't obligated to write out of order in a way that wouldn't invalidate the name even temporarily.

> ונהי דזה הוי מקלקל ע"מ
> לתקן מכל מקום בודאי לכתחלה אם יש תקנה שלא לקלקל כלל ודאי עדיף וז"פ
> ועיין בנדרים דלא יאמר לד' חטאת כו' ה"נ אפשר ח"ו לא יגמור מקלקל השם י'
> ה' ולמה לא התקינו חכמינו זכרונם לברכה בכותב שם הוי' ב"ה דיכתוב הי'
> לבסוף ויכתוב תחלה אותיות הו"ה ואח"כ יכתוב הי' בראש התיבה ונגמר השם
> ובזה אין שום מכשול ומזה ראיה ברורה דהשם צריך להיות כסדרן אלא אם כן א"א
> בענין אחר ומצותו בכך. ועיין בנו"ב מה"ק שם דמביא בפשיטות דהשם צריך
> להיות נכתב כסדר ובאמת ל"מ זה בשום מקום ולפמ"ש יש מכאן ראי' ברורה מדלא
> התקינו חכמינו זכרונם לברכה כן ע"כ מבואר דהי' אסור לכתוב בסוף מחמת שלא
> כסדרן. ועיין בס' יהושע שכתב גם כן על ד"ז דלא נמצא בשום מקום ולפי עניות
> דעתי הוא ראי' ברורה.

Implied in his reasoning is that even if one plans to write the longer Divine Name, there are issues with *mechika*. I think it is obvious that one intended to write the shorter Name and subsequently lengthens it this would at least have the same considerations.

Comment: ונראה אם רצה לכתוב שם י' ה' לחוד אסור לכתוב וא"ו אח"כ לחוד דמקלקל השם דמעיקרא היה שם י' ה' ועתה יה"ו אינו שם כלל.  Why did he only say that case, he could’ve said even if you finish writing the full name it’s an issue. From the fact that he only mentions a case that adding a a letter leaves it as a non name, it seems that if it would be making a new name it would be fine.